# How does the browser allow downloading the php file while wget doesn't? [MediaWiki installation]

Tags: php, curl, wget, mediawiki

During the installation of MediaWiki, I had to download a file called `LocalSettings.php`. When I download it by clicking on the download link (which happens to be `http://localhost/mymediawiki/mw-config/index.php?localsettings=1`), it downloads a php file, but when I download it by "copy link address" and using

`$ wget URL -O output`

it downloads a html file.

The following is the content of the `index.php`:

- https://pastebin.com/08HZeirU

The following is the content I get with `wget`:

- https://pastebin.com/d5aiG9Ph

Basically the page that offers the download link (which is `http://localhost/mymediawiki/mw-config/index.php?page=Complete`), it seems.

The following are some of researches I had:

- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/98425/is-there-a-way-to-download-a-php-file-without-it-being-executed
- [Possible to view PHP code of a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995360/possible-to-view-php-code-of-a-website)
- [Is it possible to download PHP script from a web page with wget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938624/is-it-possible-to-download-php-script-from-a-web-page-with-wget)

But I don't understand how clicking on the "download the file" link DOES download the php file. This makes me wonder ther must be a way to download the php file with some bash commands like `wget` or `curl`.

Please tell me how the browser is doing it, and any other way to do it through the termianl.

Comment: Since we probably don't have a MediaWiki install handy, can you clarify what that link looks like exactly? In general: no, the browser doesn't have any secret sauce, instead there was some difference between the two HTTP requests. Possibly cookies.

Comment: @deceze Thank you for suggesting clarifying the link. I added that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your browser has cookies, wget doesn't, it's almost certainly a file protected by cookies, only those with the correct (authentication?) cookies can access the file, wget can not. in chrome open the developer console, navigate to the Network tab, download the file in chrome, find the request in the network tab, right click on the tab and press "copy as curl", and you'll see what the request looks like *with* cookies, it'll look more like:

> curl 'https://stackoverflow.com/posts/validate-body' -H 'cookie: prov=5fad00f3-5ed3-bd3b-3a8a; _ga=GA1.2.20207544.1508821; sgt=id=e366-9d13-4df2-84de-2042; _gid=GA1.2.129666.1538138077; acct=t=Jyl74nJBTyCIYQq5mc2sf&s=StN3CVV2B5Opj051ywy7' -H 'origin: https://stackoverflow.com' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36' -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' -H 'accept: */*' -H 'referer: https://stackoverflow.com/' -H 'authority: stackoverflow.com' -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' --data $'body=your+browser+has+cookies%2C+wge&oldBody=&isQuestion=false' --compressed

- and if you run that command in bash, you'll probably be able to download the file from the terminal.

Comment: Didn't know about the "copy as curl". With the mediawiki installation. It didn't work. When I checked the request headers, the "copy as curl" didn't include `-H 'Host: localhost'`. After adding it to the curl, it downloaded the php file. THANK YOU.

Comment: @user3290525 if the original download url was on the `localhost` domain, and the curl copy was not http://localhost/, and did not add `-H 'Host: localhost'` automatically, then that sounds like a chrome bug! :O

Comment: `-o file` argument is necessary if you **really** want to save the response to a file by using curl, otherwise it will make a response to the server and nothing will be downloaded.

Comment: I had to add `--output "<filename>"` to the end of the command to save it to a file, but otherwise this is perfect. I used Firefox rather than Chrome: Menu button -> Web Developer -> Network -> right-click the request -> copy as cURL.

Answer (score 2):

As you've seen in related questions, you can't download PHP source code just by requesting the file, at least as long as the HTTP Server has PHP extension enabled.

But that by no means imply you can't download a PHP script given the right circumstances.

You can have in the server a PHP script working as proxy to bypass PHP parsing and send you source code of any PHP file in the server. It just has to set up some headers and hand it to you with a simple `readfile(filename)`. Of course, that is usually done after making sure that you are authorized.

Also, the address of a link isn't always the address you are actually accessing when you click the link. It may contain a `onclick` action that overrides the `href`, and it can be placed there dynamically so you won't know about it even if you check the HTML source code.

One easy way to figure out what the link is actually doing is to press Ctrl+Shift+C in Firefox or Chrome, go to the Network tab, and click the link to see what it really is accessing.

I bet it is not accessing the file directly like you think.