# AJAX-Driven Site

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Well, I have a completely AJAX driven site. I inserted a jQuery code that affects all forms and queries site-wide. It's to the point, even though I want to change it, I fathom and accept the idea of a website that utitlizes a single function to process all queries (search, links, & profile, etc....)

How do you accomodate speed and security to such a platform? My php files can be accessed directly from their location's link. That is a threat. Help me; as well as AJAX, I need validation and '777' protection.

Comment: You can't view the source of php files so its really not a risk, if I understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 2):

Before you read my answer read also this (as answer to a comment on your question) : 
[Possible to view PHP code of a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995360/possible-to-view-php-code-of-a-website)

Don't put **speed** and **security** in the same box.
 A website can be *secure* and *fast* at the same time.
I would secure a folder with **777** access (why not 755?) with an empty 0Kb index.html file (yes, even if you have inside a bunch of .php files!) ad put an .htaccess with restrictions `deny from all` that allows a folder to be accessed internally but not from 'outside'.

Than I would NEVER send sensitive data through the requests, but rather a client-side transformed  Hashing algorithm like **MD5** or **SHA1** to compare data and validate on server-side. So don't ever ever send sensitive data in it's pure state over the yellow wire.

Need more security? **https**

Regarding a `"single function"` that drives your **JS client-end** of the site, well, if well formatted the browser doesn't care if it's one or hundreds, a good code is a **readable** code. Performance wise there's lots of suggestions on the *www* how to speed up your code.

To add to a really good **@Tim's** comment/tip, you can still open your console in Firebug (Net) and inspect every single piece of information that is sent from your Page to the server (and vice-versa!!) and act accordingly.

Comment: To add to this Tim: perhaps you should inspect each "ajaxified" piece of code on your site and try to break it yourself. If you're still so worried then perhaps you should hire a security expert to access the issue.

Comment: You addressed a lot of issues. Nice. Thanks a lot. I will take all of it into consideration.