# PHP plaintext passwords - what's the risk?

Tags: php, security

I am learning PHP now (just for fun).

I assume that there is a great danger with having plaintext passwords in source code. But what exactly is the risk?

For example,

```
<?php
    if ($pass == "4f5s5gdx#") {
        /* do secure code */
    } else {
        /* error */
    }
?>
```

assuming that `$pass` came from a text field.

I know about `htmlspecialchars()`, to prevent code injection exploits. But what other security concerns are there with plain-text passcode checking? I know you should use hashes and salt for actual passwords (I would never use this for serious security).

Comment: Unless you're using this for an Intranet; fine. Otherwise, there are supercomputers out there that will sniff those out like a Bloodhound after an escapee with perfume all over his/her clothing.

Comment: You should take this question up at [security.se]

Comment: basically: if someone gets a copy of this script, they'll be able to get into whatever this password is protecting, because they'll have the password.

Comment: @Kermit should I migrate?

Comment: @baum Probably just search for it because it's most likely been discussed extensively.

Comment: @Kermit I appreciate good moderation and thanks for showing it on this question. I'm agree that this question doesn't entirely belong here as you said but I'm also not so sure that it is primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer should tell you how it is possible to access php files as plain text (not processed by the php parser)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2995394/3501422

If someone exploits a vulnerability on your server and gets hold of that page, they then have all passwords.

On it's own it's good security to hash or encrypt passwords combined with other methods of security it makes for a great system. Security is all about layers, you need to add as many as possible and password hashing is one of them.

Answer (score 2):

If you accidentally type a `<` or `>` that stops PHP from parsing your PHP code, or your PHP stops being parsed for any reason, then you will have a plaintext/HTML file served up to your users with your plain-text password on a silver platter.

Answer (score 0):

All php code should be processed remotely by the server, so the user only see's what the server shows them... However if you  have something like

```
<?php
    // Code here
?>
    $password = 'iloveSO';
```

or

```
<?php

   $password = 'iloveSO';

   echo $password;

?>
```

Then your password would be available for the browser to see.

A easy way to make sure you don't make mistakes is separate your passwords from the php file.

password.php

```
<?php
     // Password PHP File //

$mail_password = 'adsfasdf';
$mail_username = 'adsfasdf';

$mysql_password = 'asdfadsf';
$mysql_username = 'root';

?>
```

index.php

```
<?php

     require_once 'password.php';

?>
```

AND better yet if you have your password.php file outside your htdoc folder, it will never be accessible by the user.

```
  - password.php
  - htdocs/
      - index.php
      - images/
          - image1.jpg
```

In the folder example above you would do the following in your index file.

```
require_once '../password.php';
```