# php-Authentication always fails

Tags: php, authentication

I am trying to set up a simple athentication with php:

```
<?php

if ($PHP_AUTH_USER != "a" or $PHP_AUTH_PW != "b"):

header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Protected Page: ' .
     'Enter your username and password for access."');
header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
?>
  <HTML>
    <HEAD><TITLE>Authorization Failed</TITLE></HEAD>
    <BODY><H1>Authorization Failed</H1></BODY>
  </HTML>
<?php else: ?>
  <HTML>
    <HEAD><TITLE>Authorization success</TITLE></HEAD>
    <BODY><H1>Authorization success</H1></BODY>
  </HTML>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The username/passsword dialogue appears, but when I type a and b as the username and password, the dialogue closes and pops right up again.

I am running apache2.4, could the configuration be a problem? Which additional information should I provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the line where you check the credentials:

```
if ($PHP_AUTH_USER != "a" or $PHP_AUTH_PW != "b"):
```

The values you're looking for are stored in the [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) superglobal. So the line should read:

```
if ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] != "a" or $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] != "b"):
```

I should also mention doing authentication like this shouldn't be used for anything secure as the passwords are stored in plain text, have a look at this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23021427/php-plaintext-passwords-whats-the-risk) for some more info.

Comment: thanks for the link. I am aware that this is not secure. It is merely a test.

Comment: That security problem could be solved by replacing `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] != "b"` with a call of the proper password validation library function.